# How can I display some specific column?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this problem :

I have this following form using Django :

```
class Test(forms.Form):


    name = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Name'),
    )
    price = forms.IntegerField(  
        label=_('Price'),
        required=False,
    )
    year = forms.IntegerField(
        label=_('year'),
        required=False,
    )
```

And then to display the labels with the entries I did this :

```
{% if form %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
```

But I just want to display the label 'name' with entry and the label 'price' with entry and to give a default value to year.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

PS : I tried to use this `editable:False` but I got an unexepected keyword argument 'editable'

Answer (score 0):

To give a default value in Django form, you use `initial` like so -

```
class Test(forms.Form):
    year = forms.IntegerField(
        label=_('year'),
        required=False,
        initial=33445677
    )
    # disable a field by using disabled=True in your form
    name = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Name'),
        disabled=True,
    )
```

Read about initial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#initial)

Comment: Thx u but how can I have to display the label 'name' ?

Comment: You need the form field to be disabled so the user can not edit it, right? @JohnFichter